# Using Sed to extract data between < and >

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have been provided the following `sed` command :

```
sed "s/^[^<]*<//;s/>[^<]*</,/g;s/>.*$//" CmcComRouting.log > PTChuteLog2.log
```

which works well to extract the data between the `<` and `>`.

```
160218 003034 0053 DE(N) RoutingIfCmc1.cmccom TX: Tlg=<tlgNo=<0014: ItemIdTlg>, length=<5>, cmcIndex=<942>, itemId=<13983804>, globalId=<13983804>>
```

But, what I would like to keep is the first half of the date and time sections:

```
160218 003034
```

Is there a way to use `sed`, `grep` or `awk` to do this to keep the first part, extract everything between the `<>` and put a comma between each field?

Comment: Is that the complete string? You can use the cut command like 'cut -d " " f 1-2' where delimiter is space " ".

Comment: Hi yes that is the complete string, which works OK it's just tht it does exactly what it says on the tin, extracts only the data bewteen the < > I'd like to keep the first section the first 13 characters

Comment: Do you want to extract data from the first < to the last > or all data between each < >? Can you put the desired output? It is perfectly possible to do it only with AWK.

Comment: Edit your question to show your expected output if you want help because the output your posted sed command produces from that input `tlgNo=<0014: ItemIdTlg,5,942,13983804,13983804` seems unlikely to be part of your desired output and we don't want to have to guess.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the command as follows:

```
$ sed 's/^\([0-9]* [0-9]* \)[^<]*<[^<]*</\1/;s/>[^>]*>[^>]*$//;s/>[^<]*</,/g' <<< "$var"
160218 003034 0014: ItemIdTlg,5,942,13983804,13983804
```

Firstly, the command as it was did *not* properly extract between `<>`. There is a pair of angle brackets around all other pairs, and the previous command behaved like this: from data like

```
xyz <something<a>blah<b>something> xyz
```

It would extract

```
something<a,b
```

To fix that, I've modified the first command to

```
s/^[^<]*<[^<]*<//
```

and, correspondingly the last command to

```
s/>[^>]*>[^>]*$//
```

The last command actually worked as is, but with a greedy match – this one is more controlled.

To extract the first to sequences of numbers, the first command has to capture them:

```
s/^\([0-9]* [0-9]* \)[^<]*<[^<]*</\1/
```

So, all in all, you have (a bit more readable)

```
sed 's/^\([0-9]* [0-9]* \)[^<]*<[^<]*</\1/
s/>[^>]*>[^>]*$//
s/>[^<]*</,/g' CmcComRouting.log > PTChuteLog2.log
```

Comment: Wow, how it works I can't even begin :-) but genuis, thank you Ben

Comment: Ben, slight addition, could we put a comma between the first set of numbers and the second ?

Comment: @p.taylor Just adding this as a comment as the question is different at the moment: the first command would have to become `s/^\([0-9]*\) \([0-9]*\)[^<]*<[^<]*</\1,\2/`

Answer (score 0):

This MAY be what you want:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    printf "%s,%s", $1, $2
    while ( match($0,/<[^<>]+>/) ) {
        printf ",%s", substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    print ""
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
160218,003034,0014: ItemIdTlg,5,942,13983804,13983804
```

but without you showing us the expected output in your question we're just guessing.